# Swings: storing the selected values from List into an array.

Tags: java, swing, selection, jlist

I made a List in java as under:

```
 String names[] = {"abc@gmail.com", "def@gmail.com","ghi@gmail.com","jkl@gmail.com"};
 JList places = new JList(names) ;
```

Then in order to access the selected values I wrote in valueChanged method :

```
String[] emailID= places.getSelectedValuesList().toString[];
```

which is coming out to be incorrect ... Kindly help how should I rewrite this line so as the selected values get stored in array.

Comment: there is no `toString[]` Method. Do you mean `String emailID = places.getSelectedValueList().toString()`?

Comment: @Loki no I wanted to insert all selected data into an array of type string ,How should I do this?

Comment: is there some issue to following (for working code examples) Oracles tutorials How to use List and How to use ListSelectionListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have all selected Items as an Array you can do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    String names[] = {"abc@gmail.com", "def@gmail.com","ghi@gmail.com","jkl@gmail.com"};
    JList<String> places = new JList<String>(names) ;

    places.setSelectedIndices(new int[]{0,1,2});

    String[] emailIDs = places.getSelectedValuesList().toArray(new String[]{});

    for(String s : emailIDs){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Note:

I added `<String>` to the List, because I assume you always want to have Strings as values. That way you can get the List `.toArray()` method with a generic output. Else you'd need to get an `Object[]` (Object Array) and cast the values.

Answer (score 1):

For Storing Selected Items in String Array you can try this

```
  Object[] values = places.getSelectedValues();
    String[] strings = new String[values.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if(values[i] instanceof String) {
        strings[i] = ((String) values[i]);
      }
    }
```